# Angular websocket unable to connect to server

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, websocket, connection

I put the server on Amazon AWS virtual machine (public IP address: 3.14.250.84). I try to access it through frontend in Angular like this:

```
public openWebSocket(port : number){
this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://3.14.250.84:' + port.toString());

this.webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
  //console.log('Open: ', event);
} ...
```

And it doesn't work, why?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work..? Any errors in the console / network?

Comment: Connection timeout is the error. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Even more funny, the connection works when both server and frontend app are on the same computer or on different computers connecting to the same router. As I understand I should use public not private ip adress, right?

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked, somo time it goes through the error event. Reference is below, please tell me if it helped you

```
public openWebSocket(port : number){
    this.webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://3.14.250.84:' + port.toString());
    this.webSocket.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log('Open: ', event);
    }
    this.webSocket.onerror = error => {
      console.log(`WebSocket error: ${error}`)
    }
    this.webSocket.onmessage = e => {
      connection.send(`Message ${e} received`)
    }
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applicat

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It didn't work. I start the error is due to bad configuration of the machine. I tried to switch to http protocol and requests still don;t come in. It works only if  client and server work in the same local network (moght be on different machines).